# Create data model with multiple files in rust

Tags: rust

I want to create the following datamodell in rust.

[image: Uml diagramm of the datamodell]

In other languages it is normal to create one file for each struct. I created the following file structure:

```
.
│
┝ data_model
│   │
│   ┝ mod.rs
│   ┝ house.rs
│   └ garage.rs
│
└ main.rs
```

I need a list of houses in my `garage` struct and a list of garages in my `house` struct. But I can't include this files. I tried it like that:

main.rs:

```rust
mod data_model;
...
```

mod.rs:

```rust
mod house;
mod garage;
```

That works fine. I am able to use the structs inside the main file.

But if I do this one (mod.rs and main.rs didn't changed):

garage.rs:

```rust
mod house;

struct garage{
    houses: Vec<house>
}
```

it wouldn't work, because rust searches for the file `data_model/garage/house.rs` instead of only searching for `data_model/house.rs`.

But I don't want to move `house.rs` to `garage/house.rs` because this would look like, the house is a component of the grage. Also it wouldn't work, because I also have to include the grage into the house and that won't work, if the house is component of the grage.

Whats the right way to create a datamodel like this?

PS: I know, that there are some problems because I don't use pointers to refer from house to garage and from garage to house. But that is not the problem so far.

Comment: Creating recursive structures in Rust is very difficult, is this what you really want?

Comment: "In other languages it is normal to create one file for each struct." but not in Rust, where each file creates a module, and modules are usually made to contain things that relate to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod house;` in `garage.rs` does not work because `house` in not a submodule of garage.

What you really want is to `user super::house;` in `garage.rs`.

Note however that creating one file per type is *not* idiomatic in Rust, and you shouldn't try to blindly follow other language's idioms when learning a new language. Having one file per type is possible, but not worth the effort. It is more common to group types in a module and to split files in a logical way, with things that work together in the same file. You are also not following Rust's naming conventions (eg. types should be CamelCase).

Comment: Thank you. I already expected that one single file is the way to go. But I didn't know, if that is convention. Also thank you for the CamelCase hint. File names are snake_case in rust isn't it? Is there any list of conventions in rust?

Comment: @NelDav [There is!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/style/style/naming/README.html) And the [compiler gives warnings](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1e16864772ccf1064cda9887c6f948cb) if you don't follow the conventions. As a beginner you should not ignore them as they can be quite useful. Clippy also has some good ones to learn how to write idiomatic Rust.